# Display protobuf in provectus kafka ui

Tags: apache-kafka, protocol-buffers

I am trying to display Kafka topics in Provectus lab Kafka UI.
The topics contain protobuf data. When I check the UI, the display of the fields are in binary format , not understandable.

Below is my config file for the kafka ui :

dynamic.config.enabled: true
kafka:
zookeeper:
connect: zookeeper:2181
clusters:
-
name: local
bootstrapServers: localhost:9092
# Other Cluster configuration omitted ...
serde:
- name: ProtobufFile
#classNane: com.provectus.kafka.ui.serdes.builtin.ProtobufFileSerde==> Tried with this also
classNane: com.provectus.kafka.ui.serdes.builtin.ProtobufRawSerde
properties:
# protobufFilesDir specifies root location for proto files (will be scanned recursively)
# NOTE: if 'protobufFilesDir' specified, then 'protobufFile' and 'protobufFiles' settings will be ignored
protobufFilesDir: "/kafka-ui/app"
# protobufMessageName is the default protobuf type that is used to deserialize
protobufFile: /kafka-ui/app/events.proto
# the message's value if the topic is not found in protobufMessageNameByTopic.
protobufMessageName: EventInQ
# mapping of topic names to protobuf types, that will be used for VALUES  serialization/deserialization
# optional
protobufMessageNameByTopic:
"pkt1": .xx.xxx.events.PKT1
"pkt2": .xx.xxx.events.PKT2
"pkts": .xx.xxx.events.PKTS
"pktErr": .xx.xxx.events.PKTErr

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iw4YQ.png)

How to get the proper strings here?